# Targeting letters within a word to change colour using CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to figure out if there's a quicker way to write something like this:

```
<span class="brandname"><span style="color: #0399f0">Company</span>Name</span> <span class="tagline">TagLine</span>
```

What should happen is CompanyName gets wrapped in the class `brandname` which is a specific font, weight, and text-decoration, and then first half of the name (Company) should be in blue while while the rest of it is default (black). And then Tagline is wrapped in a class called `tagline` which displays a different font etc.

Does anyone know if I can just use the class `brandname` to target the first half of CompanyName. Looking for a way to save keystrokes for the future.

I feel like the way I'm doing it now would affect SEO. Majority of my googling has resulted in links from 2012-2014...my guess is nth-letter still doesn't exist but was worth asking for alternative.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **could** do something like this CSS only, but in this case you have to add the content you want in another color to the css part:

HTML:

`<span class="brandname">Name</span> <span class="tagline">TagLine</span>`

CSS:

```
.brandname::before {
  content: "Company ";
  color: #0399f0;
}
```

I myself would still prefer the solution with the 2 span elements.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xeyqr4w9/

Comment: ooh! using `content: "Company";` is pretty great that never crossed my mind, thank you. Any particular reason you'd prefer the 2 span elements over this? I know I'm trying to save keystrokes but if the 2 span elements is the better way to do it, I'd rather stick with it than write bad code, you know what I mean?

Comment: I just want to have the content in the html part, since its easier to understand and read if someone else looks at your code or if you have to change the content. The other thing is, that its not SEO friendly (and if i get you right SEO is important for you). 
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71072/can-google-crawlers-googlebot-read-css-content-in-before-and-after-elements

Comment: oh man I was thinking using span like that was causing SEO issue but doing it CSS way is a lot worse. Thanks twain! I'll continue to use the 2 span style to avoid SEO conflicts. It definitely is more important to me. Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same before. Unfortunately I couldn't find CSS only solution.

Then I stumbled upon [this pen](https://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx) . This uses jQuery to style the n-th  selector.

```js
/*
# nth-Everthing made with js. #

##Implemented nth- ##
:nth-letter
:nth-word


## Implemented last-##
:last-word
:last-letter

## Implemented first- ##
:first-word (faster than :nth-word(1))


## Things that work ##

Add a hover effet to each odd letter
  .className:nth-letter(odd):hover{}


Add a hover effect to :before/:after
  .className:nth-letter(odd):hover:after{}



## Things that don't and will not work ##
.className:before:nth-letter



Read more: https://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/
*/

(function($) {

  /*jshint  loopfunc:true, onevar:true*/
  /*global  jQuery:true, browser:true */

  $.fn.nthEverything = function() {
    var styleSuffix   = "-nthEvery",

    cssPattern        = /\s*(.*?)\s*\{(.*?)\}/g,
    cssComments       = /\s*(?!<\")\/\*[^\*]+\*\/(?!\")\s*/gm,
    partsPattern      = /([^:]+)/g,
    nthPattern        = /(\w*)-(\w*)(\((even|odd|[\+-n\d]{1,6})\))?/,
    wordSpacePattern  = /(\s*[^ ]+\s*)/g,
    wordSimplePattern = /\s+/,
    count,
    // To store the style per Selector
    parsedStyleMap = {},
    // CSS for the classes
    genCSS = '',


    runPeriods  = function(period, className, a, length, offset){
            var inBy       = 0,
                sAt        = +period,
                matches,
                n, zB, zE, bF, eF, oldN = -1;

            if (period === 'odd' || period === 'even'){
                  sAt = (period === 'odd') ? 1 : 2;
                  inBy = 2;
            }else if (/^\d+$/.test(period)){
                sAt = period - offset;
                inBy = 0;
            }else{
                zB   = /^(\+|-)?\d+/.exec(period);
                zE   = /(\+|-)?\d+$/.exec(period);

                sAt  = (zE)?+(zE[0]):1;
                inBy = (zB)?+(zB[0]):1;

                bF = (zB)?zB.length-1:0;
                eF = (zE)?zE.length:0;
                if ((period.substr(bF, period.length-eF-bF).charAt(0)) === '-'){
                   inBy*=-1;
                }
            }

        // Start index at 0;
        sAt--;

        for (n=sAt;n<length;n+=inBy){
            if (n < 0 || n === oldN) break;
            if (a[n] === undefined){
                 a[n] = className;
            }else{
                 a[n] += " "+className;
            }
            oldN = n;
        }
    },

    createSpan = function(className, content){
          return '<span class="'+className+'">'+content+'</span>';
    },


    processPeriod = function(classNames, textArray){
        var newText = '', n, className;
        for (n=0;n<classNames.length;n++){
            className = classNames[n];
            if (className === undefined){
                newText += textArray[n];
            }else{
                newText += createSpan(className, textArray[n]);
            }
        }
           return newText;
    },

    getClassNames  = function(parsedStyle, length, pFunc){
                   var classNames = new Array(length), i;
                   for (i=0;i<parsedStyle.period.length;i++){
                       runPeriods (pFunc(parsedStyle.period[i], length), parsedStyle.className[i], classNames, length);
                   }
                   return classNames;
    },

    prepareTxt = {
             word  : function(text){return text.match(wordSpacePattern);},
            letter: function(text){return text.split('');}
    },

    pseudoFunc = {
        first : {
            word :  function(period){
                     if (period === 'firstword') period = '1';
                     return period;
            }
        },
        last : {
            word : function(period, allText, length){
                    if (period === 'lastword') period = ''+allText.match(wordSpacePattern).length;
                    return period;
            }
        },
        nth : {
            letter : function (period){
                    return period;
            },
            word :  function(period){
                    return period;
            }
        }
    },

    loopRecursive = function (contents, allText, parsedStyle){
         var func = parsedStyle.func, text, length, classNames, className, cat, period;
         contents.each(function(){
            if (this.nodeType === 1){
                loopRecursive($(this).contents(), allText, parsedStyle);
            }else if(this.nodeType === 3){
                 text = prepareTxt[func](this.nodeValue);
                 length = text.length;
                 classNames = new Array(length);
                 for (var i=0;i<parsedStyle.period.length;i++){
                     className = parsedStyle.className[i];
                     cat       = parsedStyle.cat[i];
                     period    = parsedStyle.period[i];
                     runPeriods (pseudoFunc[cat][func](period, allText, length), className, classNames, length, count);
                 }

                $(this).replaceWith( processPeriod(classNames, text) );

                count += length;
            }
        });
        return count;
    },

    parse = function(css) {
       var matches, nthMatch, nthFound = false, i, thisPeriod, selectors, style, selector, parts, nth, pseudo, cat, func, period, normSelector, ident, className;


       css = css.replace(cssComments, '').replace(/\n|\r/g, '');

       while ((matches = cssPattern.exec(css)) !== null){
          selectors = matches[1].split(',');
          style     = matches[2];
          for (i=0;i<selectors.length;i++){
              selector  = selectors[i];
              parts     = selector.match(partsPattern);

              selector = parts.shift();
              nth      = parts.shift();
              pseudo   = (parts.length !== 0)?':'+parts.join(':'):'';

              if ((nthMatch = nthPattern.exec(nth)) !== null){
                   nthFound  = true;

                   cat    = nthMatch[1];
                   func   = nthMatch[2];
                   period = (nthMatch[4]!==undefined)?nthMatch[4]:cat+func;

                   normSelector = selector.replace('#','id').replace('.', 'class');
                   ident        = normSelector + func;
                   className    = normSelector + cat + func + period + styleSuffix;

                  if ((thisPeriod = parsedStyleMap[ident]) !== undefined){
                      thisPeriod.className.push(className);
                      thisPeriod.period.push(period);
                      thisPeriod.style.push(style);
                      thisPeriod.pseudo.push(pseudo);
                      thisPeriod.cat.push(cat);
                  }else{
                      parsedStyleMap[ident] = {element : selector, func : func, className : [className],  cat : [cat], period : [period], style :[style], pseudo : [pseudo]};
                  }
              }else if (nthFound === true){
                 genCSS += selector+"{"+style+"}"; // Fix chained selectors.
              }
          }
       }
    },

    applyStyles = function(){
        var id, parsedStyle, func, b;
        for (id in parsedStyleMap){
               parsedStyle = parsedStyleMap[id];
               func = parsedStyle.func;

               $(parsedStyle.element).each(function(){
                   var $this     = $(this);
                   count = 0; // Set to 0. We use a recursive Loop here
                   loopRecursive($this.contents(), $this.text(), parsedStyle);
               });

               for (b=0;b<parsedStyle.className.length;b++){
                   genCSS += "."+parsedStyle.className[b]+parsedStyle.pseudo[b]+"{"+parsedStyle.style[b]+"}";
               }
         }

         $('<style>' + genCSS + '</style>').appendTo('head');
    };

    // Build CSS Rules
    $('link[rel=stylesheet],style').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is('link')) $.get(this.href).success(function(css) { parse(css); }); else parse($(this).text());
    });

    // Apply Styles.
    applyStyles();

  };
})(jQuery);

$.fn.nthEverything();
```

```css
.brandname2:nth-word(1){
  color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.brandname2:nth-word(2) {
  color: green;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.brandname2 {
  color: purple;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</ br>

<div class="brandname2">Company name Tagline</div>
```

Comment: oh this is very clever. thank you. This might just be the one!

Comment: Thank you! Please also check the link in the answer to original code pen link. It has demo for various implementations as well.